# Фильтр поиска JS php

Tags: php, javascript

Имеется страница. В ней выводится список пользователей с их "ОО". В форме находится список всех "ОО". Необходимо отсортировать список, в зависимости от выбранных "ОО".

Форма и стиль для выпадающего списка:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="multiselect">
        <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
            <select>
                <option>Образовательная организация</option>
            </select>
            <div class="overSelect"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkboxes">
          <?php
          $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "******", "test");
          $sql = 'SELECT * from mou where mo = "город Тула"';
          $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
          $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          $i=0;
          while ($i<$numrow)
          { $var=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
          echo ('<label for="'.$var['id'].'"><input type="checkbox" id="'.$var['id'].'" value="'.$var['title'].'"/>'.$var['title'].'</label>');
          $i++; 
          }
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="filter" value="Отфильтровать" />
</form>
<style>
    .multiselect {
        width: 400px;;
    }
    .selectBox {
        position: relative;
    }
    .selectBox select {
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .overSelect {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    }
    #checkboxes {
        display: none;
        border: 1px #dadada solid;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 300px;
    }
    #checkboxes label {
        display: block;
    }
    #checkboxes label:hover {
        background-color: #1e90ff;
    }
</style>
```

Скрипт для отображения списка:

```
<script>
    var expanded = false;
    function showCheckboxes() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        if (!expanded) {
            checkboxes.style.display = "block";
            expanded = true;
        } else {
            checkboxes.style.display = "none";
            expanded = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Наброски для реализации:

```
<script>
if($(input[type="checkbox"]).is(':checked')) { 
}
if(isset($_POST['filter']) )
{
  $SelectedElement = $_POST['"'.$var['title'].'"'];
}
</script>
```

ОО - образовательная организация. Не знаю как реализовать проверку. Т.е. если выбраны ОО из списка, то делается sql запрос с выделенными ОО. Собственно, я правильно думаю, делая так

```
if($(input[type="checkbox"]).is(':checked'))
```

Comment: Что конкретно не работает? Что такое "ОО"?

Comment: Отсортировать нужно в PHP или в JS? Если в PHP, то можно убрать из вопроса весь CSS и JS-код. Если в JS, то стоит убрать PHP-код из вопроса, предоставив конечный (отображаемый в браузере) HTML-код. _Набросок для реализации_ мне весьма не понравился тем, что там перемешаны JS и PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы уже делал лучше на jQuery:

## index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="selectBox">
    <select onchange="filterByType()">

    </select>
</div>

<form>
    <div class="checkboxesBlock"></div>
    <div class="cityName">
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Город">
    </div>
</form>
<div id="filter_result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'types.php',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.selectBox select').html(data);
        }
    });
});

function filterByType() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filter_t.php',
        data: $('.selectBox select').val(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('.selectBox select').html(data);
        }
    });
}

function filterByBoxes() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filter_boxes.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#filter_result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Позже дополню. Надо Вам отделить JS и РНР